# In what sense not using a unit vector would "mess up" the directional derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, slope

I've read dozens of questions and answers here regarding the usage of unit vectors when calculating directional derivative, and I get that it's only a convention and not mandatory.

But the tendency to use unit vectors in the first place has still not clicked for me, so I'd like to use a concrete example given [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tdyIGIEtNU) <sub>(part of a Khan Academy video series, made by the creator of 3Blue1Brown)</sub>:

Given $f(x,y) = x^2y$, and $\vec v = \begin{bmatrix}{} \frac{\sqrt2}{2}\\\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\end{bmatrix}$, the directional derivative of $f$ at point $(-1, -1)$ is:
$$
\nabla_{\vec v} f(-1,-1) = \begin{bmatrix}{} 2\\1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}{} \frac{\sqrt2}{2}\\\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\end{bmatrix} = \sqrt2 + \frac{\sqrt2}{2}
$$

However (this part [starts here](https://youtu.be/4tdyIGIEtNU?si=11rWHptcC_2Hw-Jg&t=381)):

> This only works if your vector is a unit vector, because [...] if you scale $\vec v$ by 2 [...] the derivative will become twice the value, [i.e.] $2\nabla f \cdot \vec v$, but you don't necessarily want that, because the plane that you sliced it with - if instead of doing it in the direction of $\vec v$ the unit vector, you did it in the direction of $2\vec v$ - it's the same plane, it's the same slice you're taking, and you'd want that same slope - so that's gonna mess everything up. This is super important if you're thinking about things in the context of slope.
>
> [image]

I hope I'm not just being pedantic here, as I feel I'm missing something here, but why does "this only works" if $\vec v$ is the unit vector and otherwise it "mess everything up"?

1. Is it just because by definition, directional derivative should not include a scaling factor ($2$, in this case)?
2. Is it just because by definition, a slope is the rate of change per unit?

Or is there something more fundamental to this citation?

Comment: If think your 1. and 2. are kind of the same thing.  It would just be annoying to report velocity as "$10$ meters per $2$ hours."  Isn't $5$ meters per hour better?

Comment: If you want the directional derivative to tell you “change in value of $f$ per unit of distance travelled” in the direction $v$, then $v$ needs to be a unit vector.

Comment: The reason unit vectors are important is because directions are defined by unit vectors. For any vector $\vec v$, we can view this as $\lvert\vec v\rvert\frac{\vec v}{\lvert\vec v\rvert}$ which is the magnitude of $\vec v$ in the direction of $\vec v$. Notice also that unit vectors not only have length one but also are dimensionless. For example, if $\vec r$ represents distance in a direction then $\lvert \vec r\rvert$ may have units of meters but $\frac{\vec r}{\lvert\vec r\rvert}$ is a pure direction with no units.